# How do I read from /proc/$pid/mem under Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, process, memory, proc

The [Linux `proc(5)` man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) tells me that `/proc/$pid/mem` “can be used to access the pages of a process's memory”. But a straightforward attempt to use it only gives me

```
$ cat /proc/$$/mem /proc/self/mem
cat: /proc/3065/mem: No such process
cat: /proc/self/mem: Input/output error
```

Why isn't `cat` able to print its own memory (`/proc/self/mem`)? And what is this strange “no such process” error when I try to print the shell's memory (`/proc/$$/mem`, obviously the process exists)? How can I read from `/proc/$pid/mem`, then?

Comment: There are several other methods that show how to do this on SF in this Q&A titled: [Dump a linux process's memory to file](http://serverfault.com/questions/173999/dump-a-linux-processs-memory-to-file)

Comment: up to date [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518452/313992)

Answer (score 187, accepted):

#### `/proc/$pid/maps`

`/proc/$pid/mem` shows the contents of $pid's memory mapped the same way as in the process, i.e., the byte at offset *x* in the pseudo-file is the same as the byte at address *x* in the process. If an address is unmapped in the process, reading from the corresponding offset in the file returns `EIO` (Input/output error). For example, since the first page in a process is never mapped (so that dereferencing a `NULL` pointer fails cleanly rather than unintendedly accessing actual memory), reading the first byte of `/proc/$pid/mem` always yield an I/O error.

The way to find out what parts of the process memory are mapped is to read `/proc/$pid/maps`. This file contains one line per mapped region, looking like this:

```
08048000-08054000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 828061     /bin/cat
08c9b000-08cbc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
```

The first two numbers are the boundaries of the region (addresses of the first byte and the byte after last, in hexa). The next column contain the permissions, then there's some information about the file (offset, device, inode and name) if this is a file mapping. See the [`proc(5)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page or [Understanding Linux /proc/id/maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps) for more information.

Here's a proof-of-concept script that dumps the contents of its own memory.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import re
maps_file = open("/proc/self/maps", 'r')
mem_file = open("/proc/self/mem", 'rb', 0)
output_file = open("self.dump", 'wb')
for line in maps_file.readlines():  # for each mapped region
    m = re.match(r'([0-9A-Fa-f]+)-([0-9A-Fa-f]+) ([-r])', line)
    if m.group(3) == 'r':  # if this is a readable region
        start = int(m.group(1), 16)
        end = int(m.group(2), 16)
        mem_file.seek(start)  # seek to region start
        chunk = mem_file.read(end - start)  # read region contents
        output_file.write(chunk)  # dump contents to standard output
maps_file.close()
mem_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

---

#### `/proc/$pid/mem`

*[The following is for historical interest. It does not apply to current kernels.]*

Since [version 3.3 of the kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e268337dfe26dfc7efd422a804dbb27977a3cccc), you can access `/proc/$pid/mem` normally as long as you access only access it at mapped offsets and you have permission to trace it (same permissions as [`ptrace`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) for read-only access). But in older kernels, there were some additional complications.

If you try to read from the `mem` pseudo-file of another process, it doesn't work: you get an `ESRCH` (No such process) error.

The permissions on `/proc/$pid/mem` (`r--------`) are more liberal than what should be the case. For example, you shouldn't be able to read a setuid process's memory. Furthermore, trying to read a process's memory while the process is modifying it could give the reader an inconsistent view of the memory, and worse, there were race conditions that could trace older versions of the Linux kernel (according to [this lkml thread](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0505.0/0858.html), though I don't know the details). So additional checks are needed:

- The process that wants to read from `/proc/$pid/mem` must attach to the process using [`ptrace`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) with the `PTRACE_ATTACH` flag. This is what debuggers do when they start debugging a process; it's also what [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) does to a process's system calls. Once the reader has finished reading from `/proc/$pid/mem`, it should detach by calling `ptrace` with the `PTRACE_DETACH` flag.
- The observed process must not be running. Normally calling `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, …)` will stop the target process (it sends a `STOP` signal), but there is a race condition (signal delivery is asynchronous), so the tracer should call `wait` (as documented in [`ptrace(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)).

A process running as root can read any process's memory, without needing to call `ptrace`, but the observed process must be stopped, or the read will still return `ESRCH`.

In the Linux kernel source, the code providing per-process entries in `/proc` is in [`fs/proc/base.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/fs/proc/base.c), and the function to read from `/proc/$pid/mem` is [`mem_read`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/fs/proc/base.c#L779). The additional check is performed by [`check_mem_permission`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/fs/proc/base.c#L197).

Here's some sample C code to attach to a process and read a chunk its of `mem` file (error checking omitted):

```
sprintf(mem_file_name, "/proc/%d/mem", pid);
mem_fd = open(mem_file_name, O_RDONLY);
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
lseek(mem_fd, offset, SEEK_SET);
read(mem_fd, buf, _SC_PAGE_SIZE);
ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
```

[I've already posted a proof-of-concept script for dumping `/proc/$pid/mem` on another thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6267/how-to-unswap-my-desktop/6271#6271).

Comment: Or you can just use dd to read from /proc/pid/mem

Comment: @abc No, reading from `/proc/$pid/mem` directly (whether with `cat` or `dd` or anything else) doesn't work. Read my answer.

Comment: You are right. Please check this article. http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/         Here the author is using dd to read from /proc/self/mem. I have asked him how was he able to accomplish that?

Comment: @abc He's reading from `/proc/self/mem`. A process can read its own memory space just fine, it's reading another process's memory space that requires `PTRACE_ATTACH`.

Comment: Somehow this hits the 2GB fseek limit, I didn't get it to work in Python 3 to see if that uses fseeko. Also it needs a SIGCONT somewhere in the crash case. I know it's quick and dirty, sorry.

Comment: (I'm referring to the linked script)

Comment: Even as root, I cannot peek at another process' `/proc/pid/mem` without `ptrace`-ing. `kill -SIGSTOP pid` alone doesn't suffice. This is on RHEL6.1

Comment: Updated to work with 64-bit virtual memory https://gist.github.com/ntrrgc/9309999

Comment: @ntrrgc What was the problem? As far as I remember, I'd tested that on amd64.

Comment: file.seek will fail with 64-bit positions if the most-significant bit is 1, because offset in lseek() is signed and Python will signal 'could not convert Python int to C (signed) long'.

Comment: Hi, from what I've seen the linux-memory-dumper (https://github.com/fuhry/linux-memory-dumper) uses /dev/$pid/maps to dump memory of arbitrary process. Can you elaborate how is it able to do that, since such a thing is not allowed as you've specified? Thank you

Comment: About the high bit, I'm not aware of any solution even in C. All `lseek` functions expect a signed offset. Apparently, this is the case even at the kernel level. AFAIK, the only solution left is to use `process_vm_readv` with a recent kernel (3.2).

Comment: My previous comment is wrong: lseek works correctly even if the high bit it set: you can use off_t as an unsigned value.

Comment: Note that with recent Linux kernels, you do not need to PTRACE_ATTACH. This change comes with the `process_vm_readv()` system call (Linux 3.2).

Comment: "If you try to read from the `mem` pseudo-file of another process, it doesn't work: you get an `ESRCH` (No such process) error." contradicts "The permissions on `/proc/$pid/mem` (`r--------`) are more liberal than what should be the case.". How can the permissions be too liberal when accessing `mem` gives an error?

Comment: @Melab The owner has read permission, but in general the owner can't read the file: the reading process has to be tracing $pid.

Comment: Hm, with Linux 4.14.8 this does work for me: start a long running process that is busy writing output to /dev/null. Then another process is able to open, seek and read some bytes from /proc/$otherpid/mem (i.e. at some offsets referenced via the auxiliary vector) - without having to ptrace-attach/detach or stopping/starting the process. Works if the process runs under the same user and for the root user. I.e. I can't yield a `ESRCH` error in this scenario.

Comment: @maxschlepzig I guess that's the change mentioned by ysdx in the comment above.

Comment: This answer is outdated, as already mentioned in the comments by ysdx and maxschlepzig above. Moreover, the /proc/<pid>/mem of a setuid process is owned by root, neither the real nor the effective user have access to it.

Answer (score 32):

This command (from gdb) dumps memory reliably:

```
gcore pid
```

Dumps can be large, use `-o outfile` if your current directory doesn't have enough room.

Comment: This works really well.

Answer (score 12):

When you execute `cat /proc/$$/mem` the variable `$$` is evaluated by by bash which inserts its own pid. It then executes `cat` which has a different pid. You end up with `cat` trying to read the memory of `bash`, its parent process. Since non-privileged processes can only read their own memory space this gets denied by the kernel.

Here's an example:

```
$ echo $$
17823
```

Note that `$$` evaluates to 17823. Let's see which process that is.

```
$ ps -ef | awk '{if ($2 == "17823") print}'
bahamat  17823 17822  0 13:51 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
```

It's my current shell.

```
$ cat /proc/$$/mem
cat: /proc/17823/mem: No such process
```

Here again `$$` evaluates to 17823, which is my shell. `cat` can't read my shell's memory space.

Comment: You end up trying to read the memory of whatever `$pid` is. As I explain in my answer, reading the memory of a different process requires you to ptrace it.

Comment: Which is going to be bash. I wasn't saying your answer was wrong. I was just answering in more layman's terms "why doesn't this work".

Comment: @bahamat: Are you thinking of `$$` when you write (and read) `$pid`?

Comment: Yes...he started out asking referring to `$$` and put `$pid` at the end. I transposed it in my head without realizing it. My entire answer should refer to `$$`, not `$pid`.

Comment: @bahamat: Is the question clearer now? (BTW I don't see your comments unless you use “@Gilles”, I just happened to see your edit and came to see.)

Comment: @Gilles it was clear before. He specifically mentions using `cat /proc/$$/mem`. I was explaining why that specific command doesn't work as expected. I've updated my answer to include a specific example.

Comment: @bahamat: I assure you that when I wrote `cat /proc/$$/mem`, I expected to see the memory of the shell. (Er, did you realize that I asked the question?)

Comment: @Giles: That's why I put "Since non-privileged processes can only read their own memory space this gets denied by the kernel". (And nope, I didn't realize that until just now when you pointed it out. I thought this whole time I was trying to make it a little more clear to someone else. I don't usually look at the poster's name or rep...then again I'm new here. It makes more sense to me now why the conversation went the way it did.)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a small program I wrote in C:

Usage:

```
memdump <pid>
memdump <pid> <ip-address> <port>
```

The program uses /proc/$pid/maps to find all of the mapped memory regions of the process, and then read those regions from /proc/$pid/mem, one page at a time. those pages are written to stdout or the IP address and TCP port you specified.

Code (tested on Android, requires superuser permissions):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void dump_memory_region(FILE* pMemFile, unsigned long start_address, long length, int serverSocket)
{
    unsigned long address;
    int pageLength = 4096;
    unsigned char page[pageLength];
    fseeko(pMemFile, start_address, SEEK_SET);

    for (address=start_address; address < start_address + length; address += pageLength)
    {
        fread(&page, 1, pageLength, pMemFile);
        if (serverSocket == -1)
        {
            // write to stdout
            fwrite(&page, 1, pageLength, stdout);
        }
        else
        {
            send(serverSocket, &page, pageLength, 0);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc == 2 || argc == 4)
    {
        int pid = atoi(argv[1]);
        long ptraceResult = ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
        if (ptraceResult < 0)
        {
            printf("Unable to attach to the pid specified\n");
            return;
        }
        wait(NULL);

        char mapsFilename[1024];
        sprintf(mapsFilename, "/proc/%s/maps", argv[1]);
        FILE* pMapsFile = fopen(mapsFilename, "r");
        char memFilename[1024];
        sprintf(memFilename, "/proc/%s/mem", argv[1]);
        FILE* pMemFile = fopen(memFilename, "r");
        int serverSocket = -1;
        if (argc == 4)
        {   
            unsigned int port;
            int count = sscanf(argv[3], "%d", &port);
            if (count == 0)
            {
                printf("Invalid port specified\n");
                return;
            }
            serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
            if (serverSocket == -1)
            {
                printf("Could not create socket\n");
                return;
            }
            struct sockaddr_in serverSocketAddress;
            serverSocketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[2]);
            serverSocketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
            serverSocketAddress.sin_port = htons(port);
            if (connect(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverSocketAddress, sizeof(serverSocketAddress)) < 0)
            {
                printf("Could not connect to server\n");
                return;
            }
        }
        char line[256];
        while (fgets(line, 256, pMapsFile) != NULL)
        {
            unsigned long start_address;
            unsigned long end_address;
            sscanf(line, "%08lx-%08lx\n", &start_address, &end_address);
            dump_memory_region(pMemFile, start_address, end_address - start_address, serverSocket);
        }
        fclose(pMapsFile);
        fclose(pMemFile);
        if (serverSocket != -1)
        {
            close(serverSocket);
        }

        ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, NULL);
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s <pid>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("%s <pid> <ip-address> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation of your code. Your only comment is kinda pointless: `write to stdout` immediately above `fwrite(..., stdout)`. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/119600/beginners-guide-to-writing-comments

Comment: You said you only tested it on Android, so I just wanted to confirm, it works well on Linux 4.4.0-28 x86_64, as you'd expect

Comment: i get bunch of data like �/ ����� @8�l�/ ����� @��l  on stdout that never ends any idea why ? compiled on Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.25-1 (2017-05-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux Thread model: posix gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18)

Comment: ceph3us, the common usage is to pipe the data to a file (e.g. memdump <pid> > /sdcard/memdump.bin)

Comment: You could probably use Linux [`sendfile(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) or [`splice(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) to send the data to the output without copying it into user-space.  (And again from the stdio buffer to your local array, since you're using stdio to hopefully reduce the number of read system calls, to use chunks larger than 1 page without having to make that explicit in the code.)  `/proc/<PID>/maps` is already Linux-specific.

Answer (score 7):

Perform the read using bash can be done also with `dd(1)`

If you're on a limited and basic Unix system which doesn't have the some of the commands mentioned above (from `python` all the way to `memdump` and stuff like that)

You can use `dd(1)`, which should be available in the most limited Unix environment.

Example for dumping the first few bytes from the process:

```
$ dd if=/proc/1337/mem of=/tmp/dump bs=1 skip=$((0x400000)) count=128
```

and then you can read it with

```
hexdump -Cv ./tmp/dump
```

Answer (score 3):

you can read the mem file with the `xxd` program

in this example i'm going to read the `heap` of a program

```
$ cd /proc/<the-pid>
$ cat maps | grep heap
55fe7eec6000-55fe7eee7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                         [heap]
$
$ sudo xxd -s 0x55fe7eec6000 -l $((0x55fe7eee7000 - 0x55fe7eec6000)) mem  | less
```

- flag s: seek offset position 0x05..6000
- flag l: is the length. The last position (0x5..7000) minus the start position (0x5..6000)
- mem: file
- | less: visualize the output with less