# Read the stack of another process?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory, proc

I'm trying to read a child process's stack but with no luck.
I know it is possible using `ptrace`, but `ptrace`'s interface allows you to read only one word at a time, and I'm trying to scan a larger portions of the stack.

I've also tried reading the `/proc/$pid/mem` from the boundries of the stack as extracted from the `/proc/$pid/maps` file after first using ptrace to attach to it
(as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux)) but the read keeps failing (even when running as root) although the same code succeeds when tried reading from different parts of the process (e.g. heap).

What am I doing wrong?
Is there any other option?

Comment: Did you call `waitpid` between `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH,…)` and `read` (otherwise there's a possible race condition)? What error does `read` return? Is the child doing anything peculiar with its memory mapping — can you try your code with a simple child like `sleep`?

Comment: I did use wait after ptrace, and I've put a scanf in the child to force it to wait.

Comment: Is this only on Linux?  Solaris also has a /proc filesystem, but it's completely different from Linux, eve philosophically. Lots of "binary files".

Comment: just do a system("pstack _pid_") and parse the output ..

Comment: See [ps: full command is too long](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91562) for some examples

Comment: Please show us your code `perl -e '$p=shift;open MAPS, "/proc/$p/maps";($m)=grep /\[stack\]/, <MAPS>;($a,$b)=map hex, $m =~ /[\da-f]+/g;open MEM, "/proc/$p/mem" or die "open mem: $!";seek MEM,$a,0 or die "seek: $!";read MEM, $c,$b-$a or die "read";print $c' "$$" | hd` works for me. What do you get when you run it?

Answer (score 5):

> `ptrace`'s interface allows you to read only one word at a time, and I'm trying to scan a larger portions of the stack

Well, just use a loop, then. I honestly don't see how that constitutes a problem with `ptrace`, I use it all the time to remotely access processes.

I use something like this:

```c
static int memcpy_from_target(pid_t pid, char *dest, long src, size_t n)
{
    static int const align = sizeof(long) - 1;

    while (n)
    {
        size_t todo = MIN(n, sizeof(long) - (src & align));
        long data = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, pid, src - (src & align), 0);
        if (errno)
        {
            perror("ptrace_peektext (memcpy_from_target)");
            return -1;
        }
        memcpy(dest, (char *)&data + (src & align), todo);

        dest += todo; src += todo; n -= todo;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sam, while your code will do (and actually that's what I'm currently doing), it has a large performance overhead.

Comment: @user4536: I see. I have another strategy in mind that I'll post about when I have time writing it down. What are your typical stack sizes?

Comment: It's hard to say really as my research does not assume a specific stack size, but for the sake of this argument let's say at least a couple of pages long

Could you drop a hint regarding your strategy?
Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another strategy that might need tweaking but should be more efficient with large chunks of data. The idea is to execute syscalls in the remote process in order to retrieve the stack contents. It will need specific architecture code but if you only target x86 / x86_64 it shouldn't be too much hassle.

1. Create a named pipe such as `"/tmp/fifo"` in your calling process.
2. Step into the traced process until it returns from a syscall, using `PTRACE_SYSCALL` to step, `waitpid()` to wait and `PTRACE_GETREGS`/`PTRACE_PEEKTEXT` to check the currently executed opcode.
3. Backup the remote process’s registers and a small area of its stack.
4. Execute syscalls on the remote process by overriding its stack with your own data: `open("/tmp/fifo")`, `write()` the stack contents, `close()` the descriptor.
5. Restore the remote process’s state.
6. Read the fifo data from your calling process.

There might be more elegant alternatives to the named pipe, but I can’t think of any right now. The reason I only use syscalls is because remote code injection is pretty unreliable on modern systems due to various security protections. The drawback is that it will hang until the remote process does a syscall (which can be a problem for some programs that mostly do computations).

You can see some free code implementing most of the work in [this source file](http://caca.zoy.org/browser/neercs/trunk/src/mytrace.c). Feedback on the code is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion.

When/if it gets accepted in the main Linux kernel tree, you will be able to use Christopher Yeoh's [Cross Memory Attach](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/7/26/518) patch. See the documentation for [process_vm_readv](http://ozlabs.org/~cyeoh/cma/process_vm_readv.txt) for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily read the stack of another process using the proc file system (You will need root access for this). Before arbitrarily reading from the /proc/pid/mem you need to consult the /proc/pid/maps. A simple read in this file shows a lot of entries. We are interested in the entry marked as stack. Once you get this you need to read the lower and upper bounds of the stack. 
Now simply open the /proc/pid/mem file, seek to the lower bound of the stack and read the correct size of data.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `mems` and not `maps`?  (I can't see any `mems` entries under my `/proc` filesystem.)  The OP already mentioned reading the stack boundaries from `/proc/$pid/maps` -- what are you suggesting they do differently?

Comment: Edited the typo. I did exactly what I mentioned in my answer and it dumped 132 KBs of stack data. We need more info on what OP did wrong. Maybe OP can share the code he used for reading the stack boundaries. If he doesn't reply, I will share mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [lsstack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lsstack/%29).  It uses ptrace, just like every other successful "read another process's stack" program. I could not get a program using /proc/$pid/mem reading to work.  I believe that you can't do it that way, although, logically, you should.