# long format of ps command in Solaris

Tags: shell, process, solaris, ps

Jobs with a long command-line is not printing in Solaris:

```
   bash-3.2$ /usr/ucb/ps auxwww | grep ftf | awk '{print $NF}' | head -5
  /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btw
  /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btw
  /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btw
  /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btw
  /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btw

  bash-3.2$ /usr/ucb/ps -alxww | grep -v "alxww" | grep ftf | grep -v grep|head -5
  0 39548   737   693  0  50 20 5112 3952 603110c3e70 S ?        249:55 /usr/bin/bash                  
  /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btw
  0 39548   906   871  0  50 20 4568 3488 6034bfbf348 S ?        245:12 /usr/bin/bash   
  /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btw
  0 39548  2512  2480  0  50 20 4552 3544 603d5120df8 S ?        134:04 /usr/bin/bash 
  /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btw
  0 39548  2523  2496  0  50 20 4728 3688 602fcee1d28 S ?        135:43 /usr/bin/bash 
  /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btw
  0 39548  2557  2535  0  50 20 4472 3480 603df1e0838 S ?        133:48 /usr/bin/bash 
  /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btw
```

It is chopping off part of the configuraton file.

I also cannot use `pargs`:

```
   bash-3.2$ for i in `/usr/ucb/ps -alxww | grep -v "alxww" | grep ftf | grep -v gr
   ep| awk '{print $3}'|head -3`; do pargs $i; done 
   pargs: cannot examine 737: permission denied
   pargs: cannot examine 2512: permission denied
   pargs: cannot examine 2523: permission denied
   bash-3.2$
```

I checked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91561/ps-full-command-is-too-long), but I couldn't get the complete arguments:

Comment: What do you think the full arguments look like?

Comment: Is `ps` printing the `pid` as the second or third column?  Surely you don't have five processes, all with the pid `39548`?

Comment: full arguments look like,


       `/usr/bin/bash /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c     
       /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btws_fnhkdr.cfg

       /usr/bin/bash /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c 
       /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btws_bilvim_e2e.cfg

       /usr/bin/bash /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c 
       /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btws_giwsch_e2e.cfg

       /usr/bin/bash /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c 
       /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btws_bilspi_e2e.cfg

       /usr/bin/bash /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c     
       /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btws_cpbtdr.cfg`

Comment: In the above comment, starting command is `/usr/bin/bash` & there are 5 records.

Comment: Sorry `ps` is printing pid in 3rd column, updating the question

Comment: Found the correct solution. When i run `/usr/ucb/ps auxwww | grep ftf ` command in elevated user, it gave me complete ans.
`dcmh228z:dcmp01 $/usr/ucb/ps auxwww | grep ftf | head -2 
dcmp01     807  0.1  0.0 4392 3520 ?        S 18:14:31  1:24 /usr/bin/bash /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btws_wirwtx.cfg
dcmp01   13075  0.0  0.0 4192 3320 ?        S 19:54:01  0:00 /usr/bin/bash /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y -c /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btws_wlbai.cfg`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are making it more complex than it needs to be. No need for `awk` or ancient version of `ps` command.

Try this:

```
for x in `ps -ed -o pid=`; do echo -n "$x " ; pargs -l $x; done
```

Or when pretty printed:

```
for x in `ps -ed -o pid=`; do 
   echo -n "$x " 
   pargs -l $x 2>/dev/null # don't want to see err msg for procs that no longer exist
done
```

This will produce an output with PID and all the cmd args on one line no matter how long. Then you can grep your way through that output if you like.

Remember that `pargs` command needs to examine the process and you may not be allowed to do that for all processes .. unless you are root or have equivalent privs.

Comment: even after using above command i m still getting the same error as above
` pargs: cannot examine 20570: no such process or core file`

Comment: This worked .
          `Promt: $for i in /usr/ucb/ps -alxww | grep -v      
         "alxww"   | grep ftf | grep -v grep | awk '{print  
         $3}'; do pargs $i; done 
737:    /usr/bin/bash /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh -y       
         -c /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btw
argv[0]: /usr/bin/bash
argv[1]: /proj/cmp01/app/ftf/bin/ftf.sh
argv[2]: -y
argv[3]: -c
argv[4]: /proj/cmp01/app/btws/cfg/btws_wlsap.cfg`

Comment: Sorry couldnt format it properly. `argv[4]` shows complete configuration file

Comment: @Tingrammer. Processes come and go. My script collects the list of PIDs first and then loops these to perform an `pargs` on each of them, one by one. It may happen that a process has ended in the meantime. That's why you get that error message. If you really cannot live with seeing such message then I've updated my answer so that it now doesn't display such errors.