# Solution to get data from memory of a process

Tags: linux, process, memory

If I'm using Firefox and filling out a big form (with lots of text to write), and for some reason I accidentally press <kbd>F5</kbd> and all my text in the forms is lost, I can use e.g. [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) on Windows to retrieve the text, because they're still in memory. How can I do the same under Linux? (e.g. Fedora)

Comment: I'm not sure what your title has to do with this; are you just looking for hex editor recommendations? Or do you want something that will dump the contents of memory?

Comment: thx, updated title

Answer (score 7):

I'd try something like this:

```
strings /proc/$PID/mem | grep $MYTEXT
```

Where `$PID` is process id of your running browser program and `$MYTEXT` is a substring of the text you remember typing in.

Comment: good idea but: [root@g2 10653]# ls -lah /proc/10653/ | grep -i mem
-rw-------.   1 USER USER 0 máj   25 20.29 mem
[root@g2 10653]#

Comment: @LanceBaynes: This comment is meaningless. As it happens, I can guess that you saw an error message and misinterpreted it, but you should have copy-pasted the command you ran and the error message, not some random other command. Reading from `/proc/$PID/mem` is not straightforward, see [How do I read from /proc/$pid/mem under Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux).

Comment: ohh, thanks! I tried you're python script (you didn't wrote a small howto, how to parameter it, or how to use it?) I tried: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ZeQs50g1 - Fedora14/bash