# Exploring RAM contents

Tags: linux, memory

I am using a [redis](http://redis.io/) Database and would like to explore the contents of the RAM the application is using.

I feel the explanation of why I want to do this will make more sense then the question I would ask.

Redis is a simple key value store that stores binary data. I think it would be a good place to explore things like encoding and it would be interesting to me to do things like skimming over the RAM looking for binary sets of data, doing things like looking for simple patterns; maybe explore the idea of writing a baby query language that searched in RAM.

I had gotten this idea after reading the chapter in [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) about query languages.

Any thoughts on where to start? Initially, I want to ask "Give me the address space this application is running in, please" to the system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use gdb to access the memory of a process.

Also, you should have a look at the "/proc" filesystem - it contains pseudo files for every process; some of them may contain interesting information

Answer (score 11):

`cat /proc/[pid]/maps` according to the proc manpages.

Looks like what you want.  If you need the pid, grab that from ps or whatever other tool.

That addresses finding the address space in use.  One of the fellows at defcon last year implemented createremotethread on linux.  So you could do that...then read arbitrary memory that way.

Credit to [psusi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7285/psusi) for pointing out that `pmap -x [pid]` is easier to read.

Comment: Note that `pmap` formats this information so it is more human readable.

Answer (score 7):

Use a debugger, that's what they're for.

If you want to roll your own, it all goes through [`ptrace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace).

You can see a process's memory map (the table of contents for the memory) in `/proc/$pid/maps` and read the whole memory contents from `/proc/$pid/mem`. You can't just open that latter file normally, see [How do I read from /proc/$pid/mem under Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux)

Comment: You have been incredibly helpful with some of my questions. Do you suggest any books to read generally related to the Linux OS or particularly interesting web articles?