# How to get the Linux network namespace for a tap/tun device referenced in /proc/[PID]/fdinfo/[FD]?

Tags: linux, network-namespaces, tap

I want to correctly match TAP/TUN devices with the processes they are using, and I want to do this from *outside* of these processes using TAP/TUN devices (that is, I cannot issue any `ioctl()`s because I don't have access to a particular file descriptor inside its process itself).

I'm aware of the answers to [How to find the connection between tap interface and its file descriptor?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462722), that is: `/proc/[PID]/fdinfo/[FD]` has an additional `iff:` key-value pair that gives the name of the corresponding TAP/TUN network interface.

However, there's a problem with network namespaces, especially when TAP/TUN network interfaces get moved around network namespaces after their user-space processes have attached to them; for instance (here, `tapclient` is a simple variation of [a34729t's `tunclient.c`](https://github.com/a34729t/exp/blob/master/tunclient.c), which accepts a tap network name and attaches to it):

```
$ sudo ip tuntap add tap123 mode tap
$ sudo tapclient tap123 &
$ sudo ip netns add fooz
$ sudo ip link set tap123 netns fooz
$ PID=$(ps faux | grep tapclient | grep -v -e sudo -e grep | awk '{print $2}')
$ sudo cat /proc/$PID/fdinfo/3
```

...which then gives: `iff: tap123` -- but not the network namespace where the `tap123` network interface is currently located in.

Of course, `tap123` can be located by iterating over all network namespaces and looking for a matching network interface inside one of them. Unfortunately, there might be duplicate names, such as when creating another `tap123` in the host namespace after we've moved the first one of this name into the `fooz` network namespace above:

```
$ sudo ip tuntap add tap123 mode tap
$ ip link show tap123
$ sudo ip netns exec fooz ip link show tap123
```

So we now have **two** `tap123`s in separate network namespaces, and `fdinfo` only gives us an ambiguous `iff: tap123`.

Unfortunately, looking at the `/proc/$PID/ns/net` network namespace of the tapclient won't help either, since that doesn't match the current network namespace of `tap123` any longer:

```
$ findmnt -t nsfs | grep /run/netns/fooz
$ sudo readlink /proc/$PID/ns/net
```

For instance, this gives `net:[4026532591]` versus `net:[4026531993]`.

It there a way to unambiguously match the `tapclient` process with the correct `tap123` network interface instance it is attached to?

Comment: Note that there's `ip netns identify $PID` that should give you the net namespace of `$PID` without you having to look at nsfs inode numbers (and `ip netns pids fooz` to go the other way), but they don't seem to find anything either. Sounds like a kernel bug.

Comment: @TooTea `ip netns identify $PID` is doing nothing more than taking `/proc/$PID/ns/net` and then trying to match only against its own list of bind-mounted symbolic network namespace names. Unfortunately, that's most of the time rather pointless as few are using iproute2's bindmount positions. My example is just using `ip netns ...` to give an easily reproducable example to check the underlying mechanisms, but it's not a typical deployment situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, while user313992's hint about `SIOCGSKNS` is extremely [useful for sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76019147), the implementation of `SIOCGSKNS` for TAP/TUN file descriptors is ... *strange*: it returns an fd for the network namespace the TAP/TUN was initially created in, but **not for the current** network namespace of its netdev.

Looking around more in [`__tun_chr_ioctl`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2.11/source/drivers/net/tun.c#L3043) where `SIOCGSKNS` is implemented, reveals a highly promising [`TUNGETDEVNETNS`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2.11/source/drivers/net/tun.c#L3352) ioctl operation: this finally fetches and returns the network namespace of the TAP/TUN device.

The following unit test codes creates a TAP device in the initial network namespaces, creates a new network namespace, and then moves the TAP netdev into this new network namespace. The `TUNGETDEVNETNS` ioctl then correctly returns a fd referencing the new network namespace, where the TAP netdev has been moved already to.

```go
package main

import (
    "os"
    "runtime"

    "github.com/thediveo/notwork/link"
    "github.com/thediveo/notwork/netns"
    "github.com/vishvananda/netlink"
    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"

    . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo/v2"
    . "github.com/onsi/gomega"
    . "github.com/thediveo/success"
)

const tapNamePrefix = "tap-"

// Ugly IOCTL stuff; copied from github.com/thediveo/lxkns/ops/ioctl.go
const _IOC_NRBITS = 8
const _IOC_TYPEBITS = 8
const _IOC_SIZEBITS = 14

const _IOC_NRSHIFT = 0
const _IOC_TYPESHIFT = _IOC_NRSHIFT + _IOC_NRBITS
const _IOC_SIZESHIFT = _IOC_TYPESHIFT + _IOC_TYPEBITS
const _IOC_DIRSHIFT = _IOC_SIZESHIFT + _IOC_SIZEBITS

const _IOC_NONE = uint(0)

func _IOC(dir, ioctype, nr, size uint) uint {
    return (dir << _IOC_DIRSHIFT) | (ioctype << _IOC_TYPESHIFT) | (nr << _IOC_NRSHIFT) | (size << _IOC_SIZESHIFT)
}

func _IO(ioctype, nr uint) uint {
    return _IOC(_IOC_NONE, ioctype, nr, 0)
}

func getTapNetdevNetnsFd(fd int) (int, error) {
    return unix.IoctlRetInt(fd, _IO('T', 227))
}

var _ = Describe("TAP/TUN netns", func() {

    It("finds namespace of TAP/TUN netdev", func() {
        runtime.LockOSThread()
        defer runtime.UnlockOSThread()

        By("creating a TAP netdev")
        tt := netlink.Tuntap{
            Mode:   netlink.TUNTAP_MODE_TAP,
            Queues: 1,
        }
        tap := link.NewTransient(&tt, tapNamePrefix).(*netlink.Tuntap)
        Expect(tap.Fds).NotTo(BeEmpty())
        for _, fd := range tap.Fds {
            DeferCleanup(func() { fd.Close() })
        }

        By("creating a new transient network namespace")
        newnetnsfd := netns.NewTransient()

        By("moving the TAP netdev into the new network namespace")
        Expect(netlink.LinkSetNsFd(tap, newnetnsfd)).To(Succeed())
        Expect(netlink.LinkList()).NotTo(ContainElement(
            HaveField("Attrs().Name", tap.Name)))
        nlh := netns.NewNetlinkHandle(newnetnsfd)
        defer func() {
            Expect(nlh.LinkSetNsPid(tap, os.Getpid())).To(Succeed())
            nlh.Close()
        }()
        Expect(nlh.LinkList()).To(ContainElement(
            HaveField("Attrs().Name", tap.Name)))

        By("querying the network namespace of the TAP netdev")
        tapnetnsfd := Successful(getTapNetdevNetnsFd(int(tap.Fds[0].Fd())))
        defer unix.Close(tapnetnsfd)

        Expect(netns.Ino(tapnetnsfd)).NotTo(Equal(netns.CurrentIno()))
        Expect(netns.Ino(tapnetnsfd)).To(Equal(netns.Ino(newnetnsfd)))
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try matching the tun interface by its hardware address rather than by name (you can obtain that with `ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR)` on the tun/tap file descriptor).

I don't think there's anything simpler, otherwise a recent change like [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/f2780d6d74756bc1d7ba32ff3dd0de4afd7c7e1e) (which adds the possibility of also retrieving the net namespace of the interface via the tun fd) wouldn't have been needed and accepted.

Comment: The new `SIOCGSKNS`ioctl() you link to looks very promising, I'll look into its code to see if it does the job I'm asking for. At first glance it looks like it does, as I noticed already that the TUN clone device fd has the network namespace associated, but this cannot be retrieved from userspace later. What I'm unsure is whether it really works under the example conditions laid out above. But an interesting link anyway, many thanks!

Comment: The problem with `SIOCGIFHWADDR` and also `SIOCGSKNS` is rather that they need to be carried out on the original file descriptor because this fd's state is crucial here. Unfortunately, as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74672/cross-process-dup-on-linux points out, it's not really safely possible to duplicate the fd from the TAP/TUN user process to be used by someone else in order to issue the `SIOCGKSNS`. This leads me to believe that it's necessary to ask the kernel devs to be so kind as to add another `fdinfo` key for giving correct network namespace information.

Comment: I disagree that it's not "safely possible" to attach to a process with ptrace() and run any code in the context of that process (including sending fds with SCM_RIGHTS), but I don't have any nice and fast code to show right now. Until they add that info to `fdinfo`, and If using `gdb` is an option, you can make a list of tap interfaces, and call the ioctl via `gdb` only when necessary (when there really are duplicate names, etc).

Comment: Agreed on disagree: "safely" is misleading and I meant it to be along your "nice and fast code", deployable in production. I'm under the impression that `SIOCGSKNS` is strange as it returns the network namespace which was originally active when `/dev/net/tun` was opened. When moving the TAP/TUN later as in my example, the original network namespace would be returned, but the network interface isn't there anymore. The network namespace handling in `tun.c` looks slightly odd to me in places, especially when the stored original netns is passed but then ignored...

Comment: "SIOCGSKNS ... returns the network namespace which was originally active when /dev/net/tun was opened." that is unfortunately true ;-( wrong call, then.

Comment: with the ability to duplicate fds from one process to another, the socket option becomes again more useful.