# kernel: disabling /dev/kmem and /dev/mem

Tags: linux, kernel, security, memory

I understand that `/dev/kmem` and `/dev/mem` provide access to the memory (i.e. raw RAM) of the system. I am also aware, that `/dev/kmem` can be completely disabled in kernel and that access can be restricted for `/dev/mem`.

It seems to me, having raw access to memory can be useful for developers and hackers, but why should I need access to memory through `/dev/mem`. AFAIK it cannot be disabled in kernel (unlike `/dev/kmem`). Having access to raw memory that can be potentially abused/exploited seems to me to be just asking for trouble.

Is there some practical use for it? Do any user programs require it to work properly?

Comment: http://lwn.net/Articles/147901/ suggests that X server could use `/dev/mem`. Not sure that's still relevant.

Comment: This LJ article suggests the same thing: http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/anthony-lineberry-devmem-rootkits

Comment: Did you disable loadable modules, too? Because that's even more dangerous than `/dev/mem`. Load a module, run code in kernel mode. And on top of that, hardening against attackers with root access is only worthwhile if there are things that root cannot do, which tends not to be the case in typical installations.

Comment: @Gilles - I am using cryptographically signed modules. Only modules signed with my private key can be loaded.

Comment: Additional to STRICT_DEVMEM described in `man mem`, _write_ access to /dev/mem is disabled by kernel lockdown patches used to support "secure boot" (lockdown can be enabled without secure boot).  https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-4.12-Module-Params-Lock

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a slide deck from Scale 7x 2009 titled: [Undermining the Linux Kernel:
Malicious Code Injection via /dev/mem](https://www.socallinuxexpo.org/scale7x/sites/scale7x.socallinuxexpo.org/files/Anthony_Lineberry.ppt) that contained these 2 bullets.

> #### Who needs this?
>
> - X Server (Video Memory & Control Registers)
> - DOSEmu

From everything I've found from search thus far it would appear that these 2 bullets are the front-runners for legitimate uses.

#### References

- [Anthony Lineberry on /dev/mem Rootkits - LJ 8/2009 by Mick Bauer](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/anthony-lineberry-devmem-rootkits)
- [Who needs /dev/kmem?](http://lwn.net/Articles/147901/)

Comment: what if I don't run `X server` on my server, and thus do not need `/dev/mem`. Is there a way to disable `/dev/mem` in the kernel completely? I could only find "Filter access to /dev/mem" (`CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`).

Comment: A modern X server, under Linux, is able to live without /dev/mem, as graphic cards have their own device node. That's the case with i915 for example.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that even if you disabled `/dev/mem` and `/dev/kmem` that memory can still be dumped; take a look at `man proc` to reveal `/proc/kcore`; it is the systems physical memory. A really good forensics toolkit [rekall has a tool that does this already](https://github.com/google/rekall/blob/master/tools/pmem/linux_pmem.cc#L23); it dumps the memory (and `/boot` files) so that they can be analyzed.

As a matter of fact, [Ubuntu by default disables `/dev/kmem`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#A.2Fdev.2Fkmem_disabled):

> There is no modern use of `/dev/kmem` any more beyond attackers using it to load kernel rootkits. `CONFIG_DEVKMEM` is set to "n". While the `/dev/kmem` device node still exists in Ubuntu 8.04 LTS through Ubuntu 9.04, it is not actually attached to anything in the kernel.

Ubuntu doesn't disable [`/dev/mem` because its needed by applications](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#dev-mem).

> Some applications (Xorg) need direct access to the physical memory from user-space. The special file `/dev/mem` exists to provide this access. In the past, it was possible to view and change kernel memory from this file if an attacker had root access. The `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` kernel option was introduced to block non-device memory access (originally named `CONFIG_NONPROMISC_DEVMEM`).

### How to disable `/proc/kcore`?

[Do not enable `CONFIG_PROC_KCORE` when building the kernel.](https://dev.gentoo.org/~swift/docs/security_benchmarks/kernel.html#item-gt-kernelconfig-prockcore)

### How do you disable `/dev/mem`?

Well, looking over `man mem` gives us some details about how its created:

```
mknod -m 660 /dev/mem c 1 1
chown root:kmem /dev/mem
```

You should be able to just `rm -rf /dev/mem`; you can disable during kernel build phase by not enabling `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`.

### How to disable `/dev/kmem`?

Ensure that `CONFIG_DEVKMEM` is not enabled upon kernel build.

### How to prevent cold-boot attacks?

What if I was able to disable `/proc/kcore`, `/dev/mem`, `/dev/kmem` and then used an encrypted swap partition or didn't use swap at all? Well, [your memory could just be freezed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack) and accessed that way. How do you prevent this attack? You encrypt your RAM; how do you encrypt your RAM? You can't. [See TRESOR for details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRESOR).

Comment: I have disabled `/dev/kmem` in my kernel, and I don't see any `/proc/kcore` on my system. But I do have `/dev/mem`, and I would like to disable it.

Comment: There's typos in this answer. `/proc/mem` should be `/dev/mem`, similarly for `/proc/kmem`.

Comment: @bbb31 nice one. I thought there may have been a possibility that there was something I was missing. If that had been the case then I wanted to give you a chance to clarify.

Comment: *"How do you prevent this attack? You encrypt your RAM; how do you encrypt your RAM? You can't."* Note: In the future, you should be able to do it (at least on some types of hardware) - it's coming soon! https://lwn.net/Articles/776688/

Answer (score 2):

As you know, `/dev/mem` provides access to the physical memory of a running system. `/dev/kmem` provides access to kernel virtual memory. Both of these character devices [can be persistently disabled](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/16f73eb02d7e1765ccab3d2018e0bd98eb93d973/drivers/char/mem.c#L839) through kernel configuration options (the code is the most authoritative source of information so it is used for reference). Unsetting the first two options below will disable the corresponding devices.

- [`CONFIG_DEVKMEM`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/16f73eb02d7e1765ccab3d2018e0bd98eb93d973/drivers/char/Kconfig#L18): determines whether `/dev/kmem` is created on boot
- [`CONFIG_DEVMEM`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/16f73eb02d7e1765ccab3d2018e0bd98eb93d973/drivers/char/Kconfig#L9): determines whether `/dev/mem` is created on boot
- [`CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f986e31bb4d0dba0a10adc51308bf9de2d0e7e4a/drivers/char/mem.c#L62): if `/dev/mem` exists, determines whether access to it is restricted

Depending on your distribution, your current kernel configuration can be seen using something like `zless /proc/config.gz` or `less /boot/config-$(uname -r)`.

I *think* the initial intent of `/dev/mem` was to support interaction with [memory-mapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) peripherals.
The obvious negative security implications of having these virtual devices available (e.g. an attacker being able to on the fly patch the memory of another process or even the kernel) have been known about for at least a decade.
Restricting access to `/dev/mem` has been supported in the mainline kernel [since early 2008](https://lwn.net/Articles/267427/), `/dev/kmem` has also been optional [since around then](https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/2/10/328) too.

A decade ago it seems that `X` was reliant on `/dev/mem`, I don't think this is still true.
To test the claims about `X` needing `/dev/mem` I deleted the virtual device from my laptop yesterday and it has been functioning seemingly perfect since.
In 2017 there **seems to be no practical use for these devices** outside of research and doing development.

From a security perspective it is a good idea to remove these devices.
It is still worth noting that a *remote* attacker, with elevated privileges, can read memory outside of its address space.
Memory of other user space applications can be accessed using [`/proc/<pid>/mem`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux).
Kernel memory can be accessed using [`/proc/kcore`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243239/why-is-the-size-of-proc-kcore-file-so-bigger-than-the-physical-memory-size).

Answer (score 2):

I didn't include `/dev/mem` on my system from the start. I use Gentoo Linux, so this may come as no surprise, since with this Linux distribution you practically build every package yourself, including the Linux kernel.

I never noticed any problems due to the lack of `/dev/mem`, even when using X.org X11. Just today I noticed that an [emerge](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Portage) of the package `x11-drivers/xf86-video-vesa` prints a message stating that it requires `/dev/mem`, like this:

```
* This driver requires /dev/mem support in your kernel
*   Device Drivers --->
*     Character devices  --->
*       [*] /dev/mem virtual device support
```

Since I didn't install the VESA driver for the [XServer](https://www.x.org/wiki/XServer/) intentionally, or even if so only as a fallback I actually never ever had to use and therefore didn't notice it – until now.

But this proves the point that *a)* X11 doesn't need `/dev/mem` anymore, and *b)* that some X11 video drivers may still do anyway.

Newer video drivers for specific hardware will most likely work without it. Just like modern X.org-X11 (on Gentoo, `x11-base/xorg-server`) doesn't even have to be [suid root](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Non_root_Xorg) anymore, that's what progress looks like...