# How do I get linux-gate.dso on a newer linux system?

Tags: linux-kernel, dynamic-linking, system-calls, gdb

I would like to find out which method my 32bit QEMU guest is using for system calls. There's an excellent article explaining linux-gate.dso (http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/). However, I can 't seem to get any of the commands to work on my newer system.

It appears that current security features don't allow me to dump the virtual dso:

```
[root@qemu ~]# dd if=/proc/self/mem of=linux-gate.dso bs=4096 skip=1048574 count=1
dd: ‘/proc/self/mem’: cannot skip to specified offset
dd: error reading ‘/proc/self/mem’: Input/output error
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.0332587 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

Comment: On the topic of `/proc/self/mem`, see [How do I read from /proc/$pid/mem under Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to read `/proc/[pid]/mem`, a process must now `PTRACE_ATTACH` to it. A commonly available utility that does this is `gdb`

Pick a running process (in my case I just opened `cat` in another window), then attach gdb to that process:

```
[root@qemu ~]# gdb --pid 423
#MORE OUTPUT
0xb771dbac in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

As part of its output while loading symbols, gdb should output the line I included above. If it doesn't, you can search the symbol table for it:

```
(gdb) info functions vsyscall
All functions matching regular expression "vsyscall":

Non-debugging symbols:
0xb771db9c  __kernel_vsyscall
```

Now that we have the address of `__kernel_vsyscall`, we can either use gdb to inspect the system call method used:

```
(gdb) disassemble 0xb771db9c
Dump of assembler code for function __kernel_vsyscall:
   0xb771db9c <+0>:     push   %ecx
   0xb771db9d <+1>:     push   %edx
   0xb771db9e <+2>:     push   %ebp
   0xb771db9f <+3>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0xb771dba1 <+5>:     sysenter 
   0xb771dba3 <+7>:     nop
   0xb771dba4 <+8>:     nop
   0xb771dba5 <+9>:     nop
   0xb771dba6 <+10>:    nop
   0xb771dba7 <+11>:    nop
   0xb771dba8 <+12>:    nop
   0xb771dba9 <+13>:    nop
   0xb771dbaa <+14>:    int    $0x80
=> 0xb771dbac <+16>:    pop    %ebp
   0xb771dbad <+17>:    pop    %edx
   0xb771dbae <+18>:    pop    %ecx
   0xb771dbaf <+19>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

or we can dump linux-gate.dso as originally requested:

```
(gdb) dump memory ./linux-gate.dso 0xb771d000 0xb771e000
```

Basically, we know that linux-gate.dso takes one full page. Since this system has a page size of 4K=0x1000, I just rounded down from the address of `__kernel_vsyscall` and added 0x1000 to get the end. Outside of gdb, we can see that the file is recognized as a shared library:

```
[root@qemu ~]# objdump -T ./linux-gate.dso |grep syscall
00000b9c g    DF .text  00000014  LINUX_2.5   __kernel_vsyscall
```

and we can find sysenter again:
[root@arch-qemu ~]# objdump -d --start-address=0x00000b9c --stop-address=0x00000bac linux-gate.dso

linux-gate.dso:     file format elf32-i386

Disassembly of section .text:

```
00000b9c <__kernel_vsyscall>:
 b9c:   51                      push   %ecx
 b9d:   52                      push   %edx
 b9e:   55                      push   %ebp
 b9f:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 ba1:   0f 34                   sysenter 
 ba3:   90                      nop
 ba4:   90                      nop
 ba5:   90                      nop
 ba6:   90                      nop
 ba7:   90                      nop
 ba8:   90                      nop
 ba9:   90                      nop
 baa:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
```