# How to read files in the proc directory?

Tags: proc

I found that `ls` command can't read file in `/proc'

Please see the attachment.

[image]

There are many link files ,but you can't read it by ls.

Comment: Are you sure process 4551 is still running? Any delay between your two screenshots gives the process time to disappear, whereupon the `/proc` entries for it will also disappear.

Comment: The files in `/proc` are meta-files that contain information about processes.  You should try to do an `ls -l` to see what those symlinks are pointing to.  That may give you more insight into those files.

Comment: In your example, you didn't type "ls", just the file path. Bash reported "no such file" because it isn't an executable.

Comment: @DoxyLover if that were true (it not being an executable) you would get `Permission denied` in `sh`/`bash`. The file is not there, hence the message (and it was probably never executable either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list files under `/proc` with `ls`, and you can read their content with `cat` (with a few exceptions — [`/proc/PID/mem` is peculiar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux)).

File under `/proc` reflect the current state of the system, so they might exist at one moment and no longer exist the next moment. Some of the files depend on the current process, e.g. `/proc/self` is a symbolic link to the PID of whichever process asked for it.

If bash reports that `/proc/4551/task/4551/fd` doesn't exist, it means that there is currently no process with the PID 4551. (More precisely, there is no process with this PID in the PID namespace that bash is running in.)