# How to calculate heap size of process from address space?

Tags: linux, memory

I was trying to find the heap size my process is using. I did

`fgrep '[stack]' /proc/pid/maps`
 and got

`00a00000-45937000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]`

Now I wanted to calculate the size of the heap. So I did

`(45937000 - 00a00000 ) = 44F37000`

converted it to decimal `1156804608`. Then to GB = `1156804608/(1000*1000*1000) = 1.1568 GB`.

Is what I am doing correct?

Comment: Is this the right way to get the heap memory

Comment: Should `[stack] ` be `[heap] ` in that `fgrep` invocation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, taking the end boundary address minus the start boundary address will give you the size of the heap in that particular process.

The calculation may be carried in the shell with

```
hsize=$(( 0x45937000 - 0x00a00000 + 1 ))
printf 'heap is %d bytes (about %d MiB)\n' \
    "$hsize" "$(( hsize / 1024 / 1024 ))"
```

With GNU `awk` parsing the `maps` "file" for PID `$pid` (GNU `awk` needs `-n` to be able to recognize non-decimal integers):

```
awk -n -F '[- ]' '/\[heap\]/ {
    h = "0x" $2 - "0x" $1 + 1
    printf("heap is %d bytes (%.2f MiB)\n", h, h/1024/1024) }' /proc/$pid/maps
```

See also this related question: [How do I read from /proc/$pid/mem under Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux)

This question on ServerFault may also be useful, depending on what you would want to do: [Dump a linux process's memory to file](https://serverfault.com/questions/173999/dump-a-linux-processs-memory-to-file)